# CiviCRM upgrade in Joomla failing

Tags: upgrade, database, migration, datatables

I have got a Joomla website running CiviCRM version 5.41.2 and we are migrating to a WordPress website running CiviCRM version 5.60.0

I have backed up the Joomla site and working on a dev environment have got this running. I've upgraded CiviCRM to 5.60.0 and then started the database upgrade (following a successful component upgrade) but am getting the following fatal error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Declaration of
      CRM_Custom_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess() must be compatible with 
      CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess(): void in 
      C:\wamp64\www\iimhl\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Custom\Import\Form\Summary.php on line 13
```

If I look at the file mentioned on line 13, is as follows:

```
public function preProcess() {
    parent::preProcess();
    $session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
    $session->pushUserContext(CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/import/custom', 'reset=1'));
}
```

Comment: Database dump and load is the right approach.  What errors are you getting on the import?  Typically they relate to 'DEFINER' statements.

It is possible to switch server and upgrade at the same time, but it may be easier to upgrade your existing site to the current version first - although that won't affect your import problem.

Comment: As @Aidan says, the CiviCRM versions need to match. Switching servers is one thing, but switching CMS adds extra trickiness. I'd also recommend taking the opportunity to future-proof your installation by separating the CiviCRM database from the CMS database. I wrote a post about our experience of moving from Joomla to Wordpress. Note that that some of what we did wasn't strictly necessary (see comments): https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10052/migrate-civicrm-from-joomla-to-wordpress/35275#35275